# How to avoid new lines when utilizing lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, newline

I am trying to avoid creating new lines in the output file `pythonoutputscript.txt`. I want to avoid having new lines started in relation to the (variables/lists) mapped from the input text file. (sorry brand new to python). Is there a character I can map in front of `(par01[51])` and `(par01[53])` to keep this from happening? Thank you for help in advance!

Current output of my program:

```
EthernetCurrentConnectionInfo 
**NEWLINE**CommunicationsSendAndWait "ADDMASTER 11 
**NEWLINE**10.53.40.99 
**NEWLINE**\r",5,true,>
```

I  want it to output:

```
EthernetCurrentConnectionInfo
**NEWLINE**CommunicationsSendAndWait "ADDMASTER 11 10.53.40.99 \r",5,true,>
```

My code:

```
##INFO
A1 == 1
##CONTENT IN
inFile = open('pythoninputscript.txt', 'rt')
par01 = inFile.readlines()
if A1 == 1:
    print(par01[0:3])

##ALTERATIONS OUT
outFile = open('pythonoutputscript.txt', 'wt')
outFile.write ("EthernetCurrentConnectionInfo\nCommunicationsSendAndWait 
\"ADDMASTER "+(par01[51])+(par01[53])+"\\r\",5,true,>\n")
outFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more convenient to use the triple quoted version as template:

```
template = """EthernetCurrentConnectionInfo
CommunicationsSendAndWait "ADDMASTER {} {} \\r",5,true,>"""
```

And strip off the white space at the end of your values, using `rstrip()`:

```
outFile.write(template.format(par01[51].rstrip(), par01[53].rstrip()))
```

The placeholders marked with `{}` will be replaced with your values from `par01[51]` and `par01[53]`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you my friend! I ended up going with a variant of this that worked out great!